# not able to switch back from second pop up to first pop up using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, tcl

i am using selenium webdriver for CUCM Automation , my parent webpage gives one pop up then when we click one link on pop up it pop's up another window i am ableto move till this point but when after performing some operation on second pop up when it gets closed automatiacally after hitting the ok button then i am not able to switch back to the first pop up, rather i am providing the correct target for it.

```
testSection selectELINInfoForDefaultWindow          {gcb selectWindow -target $ConventionalERL::WindowID::ShowNewWindow1}
```

like this we swithched to first window the did some operation then new popup came and swithed on it like:-

```
testSection selectALIInfoForDefaultWindow        {gcb selectWindow -target $ERLInfoForDefault::WindowID::ShowNewWindow2}
```

after some operation we performed and it got closed then again i am trying to come to the first pop up like:-

```
testSection selectELINInfoForDefaultWindow          {gcb selectWindow -target $ConventionalERL::WindowID::ShowNewWindow1}
```

which is throwing error:

```
Caught Tcl Error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.
81: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
82: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: System info: host: 'ahazra-ws', ip: '10.77.24.165', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
83: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: Driver info: driver.version: unknown
84: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: Command duration or timeout: 462 milliseconds
85: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
86: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: System info: host: 'bgl-vtg-lnx110', ip: '64.103.217.57', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.18-404.el5', java.version: '1.6.0_07'
87: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: Session ID: 0967d3e1-6431-4591-b094-fed99a206360
88: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
89: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=0967d3e1-6431-4591-b094-fed99a206360, version=46.0.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
90: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE:     while executing
91: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: "$_webdriverObj waitForNewWindow $target"
92: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE:     (object "::gcb" method "::GuiControl::Browser::waitForNewWindow" body line 16)
93: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE:     invoked from within
94: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: "waitForNewWindow -target $target"
95: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE:     (object "::gcb" method "::GuiControl::Browser::selectWindow" body line 26)
96: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE:     invoked from within
97: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: "gcb selectWindow -target $ConventionalERL::WindowID::ShowNewWindow1"
98: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE:     ("uplevel" body line 1)
99: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE:     invoked from within
100: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE: "uplevel #0 $cmd "
101: : 2016-08-10T19:11:31: %autoeasy-5-NOTICE:
Aug 10 07:11:31 PM 2016: ERROR:  Failed command: gcb selectWindow -target $ConventionalERL::WindowID::ShowNewWindow1, Got result = 5
```

please help on this

Comment: Anyone have any suggestion on this

Comment: can anyone help on this